# Help with linq query with subqueries

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

can anyone help?, i am stuck with a linq query..

basically i have a standard linq query that returns fields, 1 field (insurances) is actually another linq query like so

```
   // original from this in etc not included to keep msg short>
    select new Models.Custom.House.Insurance()
               {
                   Id = v.IdHouse,
                   Insurances = from gt in GroupHouseTariffs
                                join  i in InsuranceGroup
                                    on new { gt.IdTariff, gt.IdGroup}
                                       equals
                                       new { i.IdTariff, i.IdGroup}
                                select new
                                       {
                                           InsuranceId = i.Id,
                                           Price = i.Price
                                       }
```

basically insurance is injected into the insurance property from Models.Custom.House, it works as i can see it in my debug ... i have 4 records in the insurance .. insurance is defined like this in House which is basically an Iqueryable of another small class..

```
       public IQueryable<Insurance> Insurances { get; set;}
```

So i tried to write an extension method, like so

```
    public static IQueryable<House> WithInsuranceId(this IQueryable<House> qry, int insuranceId)
    {
        return from h in qry
               where h.Insurance .. // BUT here is the problem i don't see my properties, I see plenty of linq methods

    }
```

I should be able to see insuranceId and do this , no?

```
    return from h in qry
               where h.Insurance.InsuranceId == 1;
```

Here is the class (its very small)

```
    public class Insurance
    {
        public int? InsuranceId { get; set; }
        public float? price{ get; set; }
    }
```

Maybe there is some sort of special lambda i need to know about :-) ?

Any help really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What compile-time error do you get if you actually say `where h.Insurance.InsuranceId == 1;`?

Comment: Well actually before compiler i see it in red but if i compile i get

'System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.Custom.House.Insurance>' does not contain a definition for 'InsuranceId' and no extension method 'InsuranceId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.Custom.House.Insurance>' could be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there typos in the sample you posted?

I noticed the following:

```
// No object name specified, Price has a capital P
select new
{
    InsuranceId = i.Id,
    Price = i.Price
}

// Price has a small p
public class Insurance
{
    public int? InsuranceId { get; set; }
    public float? price{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, your actual query looks wrong to me as well.

House.Insurance has a property called ID and a property called Insurances, which is a collection. Yet your query states:

```
 return from h in qry
           where h.Insurance.InsuranceId == 1;
```

Do you mean:

```
return from h in qry
           where h.Insurance.Id == 1 select h;
```

Or:

```
return from h in qry
           where h.Insurance.Insurances.Contains(i => i.InsuranceID ==1) select h;
```

Comment: Yes typos :-) ooops... but that was it! .. contains .. works a treat thank you